# Insert lists in SQLite database

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I've got two lists in **Python3** to insert in a **SQLite** database.
The following code works but I'm sure there is a better way.

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, vegetables TEXT, fruits TEXT)")

ls_vegetables = ['artichoke ', 'broccoli', 'celery']
ls_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut']

# Vegetables loop
id = 1
for v in ls_vegetables: 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(ID, vegetables) VALUES (?,?)", (id,v))
    id += 1
conn.commit()

# Fruits loop
id=1
for f in ls_fruits: 
    cur.execute ("UPDATE my_table SET fruits=? WHERE ID=?", (f,id))
    id += 1
conn.commit()
```

Can I have just one loop?

This is the sketch of my table:

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | vegetables | fruits  |
+====+============+=========+
| 1  | artichoke  | apple   |
+----+------------+---------+
| 2  | broccoli   | banana  |
+----+------------+---------+
| 3  | celery     | coconut |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all w/a single statement w/o any loop:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table(ID, vegetables, fruits) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    ((i, v, f) for (i, (v, f)) in enumerate(zip(vegetables, fruits), 1)))
```

Added: edited to expand index, vegetable and fruit into a flat 3-item tuple, as needed, rather than a 2-item tuple whose 2nd arg is itself a tuple).

Comment: Your solution would be perfect but I still have an error: `The current statement uses 3, and there are 2 supplied`.

This is all the code:

    import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, vegetables TEXT, fruits TEXT)")

    ls_vegetables = ['artichoke ', 'broccoli', 'celery']
    ls_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut']

    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table(ID, vegetables, fruits) VALUES (?,?,?)", enumerate( zip( ls_vegetables, ls_fruits ), 1))
    conn.commit()

Comment: Code in a comment is unreadable, but it did show me the issue w/my code -- `enumerate` does return 2 things (an int and a 2-item tuple) so they need to be unpacked -- editing to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the length of `ls_vegetables` and `ls_fruits` are equal you can `zip` them and use one loop :

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT, vegetables TEXT, fruits TEXT)")

ls_vegetables = ['artichoke ', 'broccoli', 'celery']
ls_fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut']

# Vegetables loop
id = 1
for v,f in zip(ls_vegetables,ls_fruits): 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO my_table(ID, vegetables) VALUES (?,?)", (id,v))
    cur.execute ("UPDATE my_table SET fruits=? WHERE ID=?", (f,id))
    id += 1
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Why not dispense w/ the UPDATE and specify all values in the INSERT?